# Squid reverse-proxy to Wordpress vhost

Tags: virtualhost, wordpress, squid

I have an AWS VM running Ubuntu with Apache2. I have two vhosts, both pointing to different Wordpress installs. I want to set up a Squid reverse proxy for only one of the vhosts.

My squid.conf reads:

```
http_port 80 accel defaultsite=wordpress.mysite.com no-vhost
cache_peer wordpress.mybackendserver.com parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=myAccel
acl our_sites dstdomain wordpress.mysite.com
http_access allow our_sites
cache_peer_access myAccel allow our_sites
cache_peer_access myAccel deny all
```

To test it, I set up an entry for wordpress.mysite.com in /etc/hosts pointing to the ip of the Squid server.

When I try to go to the site with the wordpress.mysite.com URL I get the default Apache2 home page.

Is there something I need to do in the http_port statement to get the url passed correctly to Apache so it can return the content for the right vhost?

Comment: Why are you using squid for this?

Comment: As I stated in the title, for a reverse proxy. We don't want the Wordpress server exposed to the outside world.

Comment: But why are you using _squid in particular_ rather than something that was actually intended to be a reverse proxy?

Comment: Squid can be both a forward and reverse caching proxy.

Comment: Maybe, but that doesn't mean it's the best tool for the job.

Comment: Everyone has an opinion about that...

Comment: True enough.. but according to your answer, you now have the same opinion!

Comment: With Wordpress, no, because we have several Wordpress sites on the same IP using vhosts. But if that were not the case it would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it won't work unless I assign a unique IP to each vhost. I wound up using the underlying Apache server and implemented the reverse proxy that way. Worked fine on the first try.